# How to store certain characters as different characters within an if statement

Tags: c#

Is there a way to store certain characters as another character within an if statement. Eg, if someone writes in 'a', store every a as 'a1'
(only within an if statement)
Thanks

Comment: No idea what you want.

Comment: Writes + into what? a text box? a console? with a stylus pen? your question is too broad and unclear. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temporary variable like `temp` & replace all your `+` with `+-`. Use that temporary variable inside if statement.

```
string myvar = "abcd+efgh";
string temp = myvar.Replace("+", "+-");

if()
{
    // use this temp variable
}
```

Comment: Is this solution you want ?

Comment: Better to initialise `temp` inside the `if`, assuming that's the only place its used.

Comment: I dont know if the user wants to use the temporary variable inside the if statement or in the if parenthesis `()`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for replace any text with other one? 
then try

```
yourText = yourText.Replace("+", "+-");
```